# Laravel 4 paginate on GET request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I have a form that is used to filter results for a categories page. So, the URL will be `localhost/public/search?keyword=blue` however when I attempt to paginate() them the URL shows up as `localhost/public/search?page=2` and so on. If I manually add the `page=2` part to the end of the url it works fine but it's not adding it to the URL with the get request as needed. It needs to show up as `localhost/search?keyword=blue&page=2`

Not sure if needed but here is my method that handles the `paginate()`

```
        $category = Inventory::select('inventory_images.image', 'inventory.id' , 'inventory.sku', 'inventory.name', 'inventory.price', 'inventory_categories.category')
            ->join('inventory_categories', 'inventory.sku', '=', 'inventory_categories.sku')
            ->leftJoin('inventory_images', 'inventory.sku', '=', 'inventory_images.sku')
            ->where('inventory.active', '=', 1)
            ->where('inventory.stock_quantity', '>', 2)
            ->where('inventory.description', 'LIKE', '%'. Input::get('keyword') . '%')
            ->orWhere('inventory.name', 'LIKE', '%'. Input::get('keyword') . '%')
            ->groupby('inventory.id')
            ->take(1000)
            ->paginate(16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your view file, where pagination is printed.
You need to append query parameters to links generated by Eloquent's paginator - which is pretty simple!

```
<div class="pagination">
    {{ $model->appends(Input::except('page'))->links() }}
</div>
```

**Note:** you must append everything except the `page` query parameter. If you don't, it would be included twice in the URL.